# Convert from 'OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Mat' to 'Numpy.NDarray'

Tags: c#, numpy, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a pupil detector in Unity 3d (2019.2.3f1) that will use a webcam to stream image frames into a Keras model for inference. As a part of it, I am using the OpenCVForUnity asset from the store. The challenge I am having is the arg of the model.Predict method takes Numpy.NDarray so I need to convert the OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Mat object to a Numpy.NDarray.

Could someone please help me figure this out? After numerous searches and reading docs I am unable to.

Thank you.

```
public Numpy.NDarray prediction(Mat image)
{
    var model = Keras.Models.Model.ModelFromJson(jsonAIModel);
    model.LoadWeight(aiModelWeights);
    //need to convert the image object to Numpy.NDarray here
    var result = model.Predict(image);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Never heard of any of the types you are mentioning .. could you add some links to the libraries you are using ...?

Comment: OpenCVForUnity is a product by Enox Sofware. Here is a link for the API: https://enoxsoftware.github.io/OpenCVForUnity/3.0.0/doc/html/annotated.html and specifically here is the class reference from the OpenCVForUnity's site for OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Mat: https://enoxsoftware.github.io/OpenCVForUnity/3.0.0/doc/html/class_open_c_v_for_unity_1_1_core_module_1_1_mat.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need it . But for whoever does..

This is limited to regular images.. You have to obviously keep in mind that opencv reads as BGR and not RGB. This seems to work for me.

```
   Mat ndarray2mat(NDArray a)
    { 
        int[] arr_shape = a.shape;
        int rows = arr_shape[0];
        int cols = arr_shape[1];
        Mat m = new Mat(rows, cols, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        byte[] array = a.ToByteArray();
        m.put(0, 0, array);
        return m;
    }
    NDArray mat2ndarray(Mat m)
    {
        int rows = m.rows();
        int cols = m.cols();
        byte[] arr = new byte[rows*cols*3];
        m.get(0, 0, arr);
        var numpy_array = np.array(arr);
        numpy_array = numpy_array.reshape(new int[] { rows, cols, 3 });
        return numpy_array;
    }
```